# How to mount a partially damaged disk in an ubuntu LiveCd boot

Tags: mount, data-recovery

Sudeenly a friend's windows disk stop working (when you trying to boot it, you can see the message: Non-System disk or disk error replace and strike any key when ready.

So I booted from a Ubuntu's LiveCD and expected to get her disk mounted. Well, it didn't...

So, what I want to do is to acces this disk data to recover the files. Could you please help me?

The problem is that this disk isn't in fstab and when I look inside /dev what I see is:

```
./by-id:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 120 ene 15 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 ene 15 10:29 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 ene 15 10:30 ata-FUJITSU_MHW2120BH_NZ1DT7730D0K -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 ene 15 10:30 ata-TSSTcorp_CDDVDW_TS-L632H -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 ene 15 10:30 usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_2.0_5B830900004B-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 ene 15 10:30 usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_2.0_5B830900004B-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1

./by-label:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 ene 15 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 ene 15 10:29 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 ene 15 10:30 PENDRIVE -> ../../sdb1

./by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 ene 15 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 ene 15 10:29 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 ene 15 10:30 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 ene 15 10:30 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1

./by-uuid:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 ene 15 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 ene 15 10:29 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 ene 15 10:30 7482-7C6A -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  11 ene 15 10:30 90951fb7-d63c-415a-bed2-1a6ca944f428 -> ../../loop1
```

As you can see the 'ata-FUJITSU_.....' can be seem by id, but not by label, path nor uuid - and the bad thing is that I'm a noob and don't know how to mount disks "by id".

Also, when I try the "gui smart test tool" it says that faild to that disk.

Some extra data that might be useful:

sudo fdisk -lu:

```
Disco /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 14593 cilindros, 234441648 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x570a7939

Disposit. Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema

Disco /dev/sdb: 4005 MB, 4005560320 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 486 cilindros, 7823360 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x0007e6ff

Disposit. Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sdb1   *          63     7823359     3911648+   b  W95 FAT32
```

sudo blkid:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/loop1: UUID="90951fb7-d63c-415a-bed2-1a6ca944f428" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="PENEDRIVE" UUID="7482-7C6A" TYPE="vfat"
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see /dev/sda1, I see only /dev/SDA/.
Probably you have destroyed your windows partition.
Can you see on gparted the windows partition? 
Probably you can't recover any data....

If you deleted only the first sectors(that contain partition table) you can try to recover it with hiren's tools.

This is all i know, i hope that other can be more usefull.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've just googled hirens tools and will give it a try. Thanks a lot!